# How to create menu in phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova

I am creating a phonegap project and i am new to this area.

I am trying to develop a menu for eg in samsung mobiles there is a menu button, so when I press the menu button a menu option will pop up. But how to have this same in nexus 5 where there is no menu button. How can i achieve it. I don't know how to search for it.

Can anyone give guide me.

hope you understand the question

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have look at various Javascript Frameworks ( jquery mobile, Dojo Mobile, Kendo UI, Ionic, Sencha Touch and many more). First and foremost you have to be familiar with HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript even if you use any of the above mentioned frameworks.

Comment: You can find a menu implementation here :
http://www.raymondcamden.com/2012/5/30/Example-of-adding-menu-support-to-a-PhoneGap-Application

Answer (score 0):

There is a framework is very useful to develop a beautiful ui: ionic
http://ionicframework.com/